# Saying selichos before midnight

Tags: tefilla, minhag, maariv, selichot

What is the position with saying *selichos* (end of *Elul* and *Aseres Ymei Teshuva*) with a *minyan* that starts straight after *maariv* at say 10:30 or 11pm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the *poskim* said you can't say *slichot* before midnight. Harav Moshe Feinstein said that it's possible in *she'at hadchak* - if it's very very hard to say them after midnight.

You can see more details in Hebrew [here](http://www.inn.co.il/Besheva/Article.aspx/6862).

Comment: Avital, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for contributing this answer!

Comment: R. Moshe (OH 2:105) says that for a congregation that won't be able to gather after midnight, then it is better to say them before than to nullify selichos altogether. Which is why many shuls with either many young children or many elderly tend to have selichos quite early in the evening, since otherwise most of the congregation would not come to selichos. R. Moshe says this would fall under the geder of "hora'ast shah"

Answer (score 4):

For more discussion, including a proper interpretation of Igros Moshe, see:

[Saying Selichot before Chatzot - Igrot Moshe Orach Chaim 2:105 and Yechaveh Da'at 1:46](http://learningteshuvot.blogspot.com/2010/08/saying-selichot-before-chatzot-igrot.html)

Besides nicely summarizing R. Moshe's view (which I corrected in a comment to the answer above), he also quotes the view of R. Ovadya that perhaps if one cannot say it past midnight, it should be said instead before mincha.

And here: [When is the proper time to say selichos?](http://jewishworker.blogspot.com/2005/09/when-is-proper-time-to-say-selichos.html)

R. Willig expresses a preference for reciting them after mincha if after midnight is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Rav Ovadia says that not only is it forbidden, but if you find yourself in a place that is doing it, it is forbidden to say amen and you should leave the place, especially if they want to count on you for the minian.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: see hazon ovadia and ialcut iosef, when I get home I can check which page exactly